# Factor polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ into 2 polynomials of equal degree

Tags: computer-science, finite-fields, computational-mathematics

Given $p \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, fast way to find $a, b$, of equal degree, such that $p=ab$.

I am aware of, for example, Berlekamp's algorithm; however, was hoping the added constraints would permit a faster solution.

I cannot claim to have been able to make the slightest headway on this.

Comment: For low degree, we just can compare coefficients on both sides of $p(x)=a(x)b(x)$, and solve the system of equations over $\mathbb{F}_2$ quickly.

Comment: If you know that $a$ and $b$ are both irreducible then characteristic two variant of Cantor-Zassenhaus may work. But I'm not really well informed about this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This was somewhat more my thinking(ish). What would this look like? We have $degree(p)$ equations, each a linear equation with terms of the form $a_ib_j$